# Psexec doesnt execute .bat

Tags: powershell, system-administration, psexec

Ive been looking in other posts and i dont know why this script isnt working, ive been looking for syntax error.The script copies the .bat file fine in C: ,the .bat works locally, but remotely doesnt get executed (i have tried with various domain users, local admin of the pcs). And PSEXEC gives me no error (ERROR 0) help appreciated.

```
$usuario = 'ADMIN'
$password = 'XXXX'


$rutaLog = "D:\SCRIPTSM\ALV\DESPM\fallos.log"
$fecha = (Get-Date).ToString('dd.MM.yyyy "y en esta hora" HH:mm:ss')
$prumod = 'D:\SCRIPTSM\ALV\DESPM'

$equipos = Get-Content D:\SCRIPTSM\despliegueFi\equipos.txt

foreach ($equipo in $equipos){
    if (test-connection -ComputerName $equipo -Count 1 -Quiet){

         Copy-Item -Path $prumod\prueba.bat \\$equipo\c$
         Set-Location -Path "D:\SCRIPTSM\PSTools"
         .\psexec.exe \\$equipo -u $usuario -p $password -h "C:\prueba.bat"
         Set-Location -Path $prumod
   
    }else{
         Set-Location -Path $prumod
         Write-Output "Equipo apagado/no se accede en esta fecha $fecha --> $equipo" >> $rutaLog
    }
}
```

The exit of the command, and the file gets copied on the remote pc.The .bat is trying to change registry keys.

```
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

La operaci¢n se complet¢ correctamente.

La operaci¢n se complet¢ correctamente.

.\psexec.exe : Connecting to X.X.X.X...
En D:\SCRIPTSM\ALV\DESPM\MODU2.ps1: 20 Carácter: 10
+          .\psexec.exe \\$equipo -u $usuario -p $password -h "C:\prueb ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Connecting to X.X.X.X...:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Starting PSEXESVC service on X.X.X.X...
Connecting with PsExec service on X.X.X.X...
Starting C:\prueba.bat on X.X.X.X...
C:\prueba.bat exited on X.X.X.X with error code 0.
```

Comment: You may need to do `CMD /C C:\PRUEBA.BAT`. You should also probably copy it to `\\$equipo\c$\ ` instead of `\\$equipo\c$`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin still not working, and no new errors executing PSEXEC. Ty tho

Comment: I don't think this is a PowerShell issue (what happens if use the `PSExec` command from a `CMD` command prompt?) Why not using a [remote PowerShell cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands) that are designed for this?

Comment: @iRon in this case i cant use normal Powershell comands because gpos/firewall issues of my company on these specific pcs thats why im obligated to use PSEXEC and yes i tried through CMD but it doesnt throw any errors.

Comment: "*and yes i tried through CMD but it doesnt throw any errors*", good that means that it is not a PowerShell issue where you stated also stated: "*And PSEXEC gives me no error*". If you don't get an error how do you determine "*remotely doesnt get executed*"/"*still not working*"? What happens if you troubleshoot and build a [mcve], e.g.: Open a PowerShell prompt and give the command: `psexec \\yourmachinename -u <yourUsername> -p <yourPassword> cmd`? If that works what happens if you fire any of your `C:\prueba.bat` bat file` commands?. Please put these type of details in the *question*.

Comment: Unless `C:\prueba.bat` is present on every target machine, you'll need the `-c` option of [`psexec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec), to ensure that it gets copied there first.